# memory leakage in CCAction in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, cocos2d-iphone

I want to cleanup memory. Here is my code

```
   [[CCActionManager sharedManager] removeAllActionsFromTarget:currentValue];
```

But this is holding memory, it is being leakage. What I have to modify to stop action and free memory?

Answer (score 0):

CCNode has a method called `stopAllActions`

```
[sprite stopAllActions];
```

This performs the method you are calling above.

It doesn't leak memory as far as I can see. The object itself is a singleton, it will never get released.